# In Node, how do I elegantly handle requiring modules that read files in their directories?

Tags: node.js, path, require

For instance, in my project directory, I have:

```
|--bar.js
|--dir
   |--foo.txt
   |--readfile.js
```

readfile.js:

```
const fs = require('fs');

var foo = fs.readFileSync('foo.txt', 'utf8');

console.log(foo);

module.exports = {foo};
```

Running `node readfile.js`, everything works perfectly.

bar.js:

```
const readfile = require('./dir/readfile');

console.log(read.foo);
```

Running `node bar.js`, I get:

fs.js:663
  return binding.open(pathModule.toNamespacedPath(path),
                 ^

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'foo.txt'
    at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:663:18)
    at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:568:33)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/fterh/Documents/Projects/playground/dir/readfile.js:3:14)
    at Module._compile (module.js:660:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:671:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:573:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:513:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:505:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:604:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
Fabians-MacBook-Pro:playground fterh$
```

I know it has to do with `require('./dir/readfile')` in bar.js, because Node then tries to search for "foo.txt" in the same directory as "bar.js". Currently, my fix is to use `path.dirname(__filename)` to get absolute paths, which would work regardless of whether I'm running the module directory or requiring it. I'm wondering if there is a more elegant way of doing things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use of [`require.resolve`](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_require_resolve_request_options) within `readfile.js` as follows:

```
const fs = require('fs');

let foo = fs.readFileSync(require.resolve('./foo.txt'), 'utf8');

console.log(foo);

module.exports = {foo};
```

**Note**: in the original question for `bar.js` it may have  been intended to write: `console.log(readfile.foo);`.

**`require.resolve`**:

> ... return the resolved filename

Answer (score 0):

Use `__dirname` to construct your path as that will always point to the directory where your module was loaded from, regardless of the current directory.  This is one of the variables that is passed into a module so it has a unique value in the scope of each module and it's purpose is for exactly what you want (to do file operations relative to your module's directory).

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

var foo = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'foo.txt'), 'utf8');

console.log(foo);

module.exports = {foo};
```

Reference info for `__dirname` [here](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/modules.html#modules_dirname).